# AppComponent.html:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subcribe' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular2-services

Hi I am new to AngularJs 2.

I am creating simple application to read Github API.

When i am starting the application with the following files, i am getting the following error:

**AppComponent.html:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subcribe' of undefined**

Below are my service and component ts files.

github.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()

export class GithubService{
    private username: string;
    private client_id = "client_id";
    private client_secret = "client_secret";

    constructor( private _http: Http){
        console.log("Github service is ready...");
        this.username = "graphicsmanoj";
    }

    getUser(){
        this._http.get('http://api.github.com/users/'+this.username+'?client_id='+this.client_id+'&client_secret='+this.client_secret).map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

profile.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { GithubService } from '../services/github.service';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'profile',
    templateUrl: 'profile.component.html',
})
export class ProfileComponent  {
    constructor(private _githubService: GithubService){
        this._githubService.getUser().subcribe(user => {
            console.log(user);
        })
    }
}
```

***Thank you very much in advance for the solution given.***

Comment: @Momin please remember when you past code, remove sensitive information like client_id and client_secret. I've removed that for you now, but please remember this in the future.

Comment: Okay ! but where i do that ?

Comment: @Momin the code you wrote in this question contained "client_id" and "client_secret". Just be careful when you write question not to include any sensitive information. I would suggest you go to https://github.com/settings/tokens and delete the old one and create a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shoulb be **`subscribe`**,

Change to

```
this._githubService.getUser().subscribe(user => {
            console.log(user);
})
```

and change your service as,

```
  getUser(): Observable<any> {
       return this._http.get('http://api.github.com/users/'+this.username+'?client_id='+this.client_id+'&client_secret='+this.client_secret).map(res => res.json());
    }
```

Comment: Hi Sajeetharan, thank you for your replay. While adding code it is miss spelled here. even with subscribe also it is giving error.

Comment: it is showing with red underline in my code editor. when i mouse over, it is showing the following message.

[ts] Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'.

Comment: change your method inside getservice as getUser(): Observable<any>

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined in console

Comment: can you please tell me what is Observable<any>

Comment: @Manoj here you can read about return types in TypeScript https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html

Comment: @Manoj when you subscribe it should return an observable

Comment: Thank you very much for your support Sajeetharan.

Answer (score 0):

In your `GithubService` you need to return the result of `this._http.get`.

```
@Injectable()
export class GithubService{
    ...

    getUser(): Observable<any> {
        // return was missing
        return this._http.get('http://api.github.com/users/'+this.username+'?client_id='+this.client_id+'&client_secret='+this.client_secret).map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```